# Uber API opening Ride Request Widget on iOs even with the Uber app installed.

Tags: ios, uber-api

If I understood correctly the Uber API would open the Uber app via deep link if the Uber app is installed on the device, and would open the Ride Request Widget if the Uber app was not installed on that particular device. On one device we tested this behaviour is normal. On other devices, the widget opens regardless of whether the Uber app was installed or not. Cant seem to find a solution. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you need to add "uber" & "uberauth" to the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes entry in your Info.plist. Is the device that it works on running iOS 8?

Otherwise, make sure your Uber app is updated to the latest version

Comment: Thanks. All those accounted for. We just removed the widget so that all will be deeplinked. I have a follow up question please; 

Is there a way to fetch info (time away/fare estimate) from the Uber API using purely deeplinking. I want users to preview this info on my app, but to be deeplinked to the Uber App as opposed to the Ride Widget. The problem is that fetching this info needs authorization, which only the widget provides.


(Resource
GET /v1/estimates/price
Authorization
OAuth 2.0 bearer token or server_token)


Is there another way?

Comment: Answered you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997052/is-there-any-way-to-fetch-info-from-the-uber-api-time-away-fare-to-destination/38001474#38001474). But short answer is that you can use server_token without having to authorize a user.